Battery on my 2022 ford bronco sport
I was just wondering if a battery can go bad due to other problems in the car for instance the purge valve going bad the turbo charger going out or a catalytic converter could any of these be a reason why a battery would go bad or what is dtc code 9g8 v4p8 this is a code from a battery test at a shop what does it mean


How do I know when someone answers my question

As below with @FDryer ... they have posted an answer. If that answer solves your issue, you can click the checkmark below the voting buttons for it. If it doesn't fix your issue, you can wait to see if anyone else answers for you. If you figure out what is going on (so you have your answer) before someone else posts it, feel free to input the fix as an answer for yourself, then check the mark when allowed to do so (I believe you can do it 24 hours after posting).

Unless you left lights on, phone charger on, dome light on, have other  issues discharging the battery overnight or the charging system is faulty, anyone can guess without more info. Check your personal setup to allow email/phone/text notification. The rated cold cranking amperage is for a new battery and as they age, lose their capacity. Average battery life is around 5 years. This becomes a problem in very cold winter temps of no start issues, poor cranking. You can try Autozone or your favorite auto store selling car batteries for the same battery test if you're in doubt. Results should be similar with a recommendation of replacement.
